# JPA JOIN query list giving only one item instead of all items

Tags: java, sql, xml, jpa, join

the following sub is giving me only one item( Carte) from the database instead of giving me all of the items . i have spent hours trying to find the error please help me guys

```
  @Path("userid/{clientid}")
  @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public ArrayList<Carte> findUserid(@PathParam("clientid") Integer clientId) {
    Utilisateur u1 = new Utilisateur();
    u1.setId(clientId);
    ArrayList<Carte > arraycarte= new ArrayList<Carte >();

    Query query1=em.createQuery("select ca FROM Carte ca left join Compte  c on c=ca.compteid left join Utilisateur u on u= c.clientid where u.id=:clientid");
    arraycarte.addAll(query1.setParameter("clientid", u1.getId()).getResultList());

    return arraycarte;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT ca
FROM Carte ca LEFT JOIN
     Compte c
     ON c = ca.compteid LEFT JOIN
     Utilisateur u
     ON u = c.clientid
WHERE u.id = :clientid;
```

Your `where` clause is undoing the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because the result is `NULL` when the user does not match. You can fix this by moving it to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT ca
FROM Carte ca LEFT JOIN
     Compte c
     ON c = ca.compteid LEFT JOIN 
     Utilisateur u
     ON u.id = c.clientid AND u = :clientid;
```

You say your query works, but it seems odd that you are referring to table names as column names. I assume this is the result of a typo. In other words, I would expect a query like this:

```
SELECT ca.*
FROM Carte ca LEFT
-----------^
     Compte c
     ON c.compte_id = ca.compteid 
----------------------^ LEFT JOIN
     Utilisateur u
     ON u.id = c.clientid AND u.id = :clientid;
------------------------------^
```